# MediaWiki links to new articles don't work even after the new article is created until the page with the link is edited

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I'm experiencing this issue with MediaWiki 1.23.6.

First I update the Main Page with a link to a new article:

```
[[New Article]]
```

Then I click on that link (which is red because the article doesn't exist yet) and create the article.

Then I go back to the Main Page.

The link to `[[New Article]]` still appears red instead of blue. MediaWiki doesn't detect that the article exists until I edit Main Page again.

It's not a browser cache issue. And I don't have any caching enabled in LocalSettings.php either. What's going on?

```
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE;
```

Comment: @Alex correct, I have full control on the server

Answer (score 3):

Configure [the wiki job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue#Performance_issue). Link colour is not updated immediately across all of your wiki to save on resources.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it takes time for the server to apply the updates to the site. If you edit the main page, it most likely implies that the article exists and is not spam temporarily. It's hard to explain, but the server basically has a "hole" which allows for your site to be valid upon edit.

I believe if you wait for a while, the link should automatically valid without the need to edit the page.

Comment: That implies that there is some cache involved.   Do you know what that cache is or how to tune it?

Comment: I created an article as a test, and the link to it still hasn't updated an hour later. That should be plenty of time. On another server I have MediaWiki 1.22.6 running and it updates immediately. So this is either configurable, or there's a problem with something